# Getting a multi-dimensional array from a text file in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0

So, this should be a simple one but I am scratching my head with it.
I have an array that I need passed in this format

```
$itemArray = @(('Valley1','111.111.111'), ('Valley2','111.111.112'), ('Valley3','111.111.113'));
```

And I need to get it from a text file that is formatted like this

```
Valley1,111.111.111
Valley2,111.111.112
Valley3,111.111.113
```

My code is currently throwing an error of "Cannot convert argument "items" with value "System.Object[]"
So I am trying to figure out the best way to get from point A, the text file, to point B, the $itemArray format I need with that data, attached is the code below, thanks for looking!

https://pastebin.com/nyMtcczF

Comment: Does it need to be array in array or will Array into PsObject work?

Comment: i would look into using `Import-Csv` since that looks like a headerless csv file. someting like `Import-Csv -Path $YourFile -Header 'Col1', 'coll2'` otta give you an array of those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the text file.

```
Valley1,111.111.111
Valley2,111.111.112
Valley3,111.111.113
```

This should work.

```
$Arrays = @()
Get-Content C:\TEST\Test.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $Arrays += , @($_ -split ",")
}

$Arrays[0]
```

This would return...

```
Valley1
111.111.111
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked and merged nicely into the main script, quick secondary question, if I only have one string/object in the array, it seems to break and returns
`V
1`

Comment: give me a example

Comment: Instead of 

Valley1,111.111.111
Valley2,111.111.112
Valley3,111.111.113

Try it with just the first line in the text file, sorry im still learning the mini formatting here lol.

Comment: So ill add that in one sec

Comment: Done the new example should fix that